# FirebaseJobDispatcher onStopJob not triggering

Tags: android

I am starting a Job when outgoing call or incoming call happened

```
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("MobileNumber", number);
    bundle.putString("CallStatus", "OUT");
    FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(ctx));
    Job myJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
            .setService(FirebaseRecordingService.class) // the JobService that will be called
            .setTag("my-unique-tag1")        // uniquely identifies the job
            .setExtras(bundle)
            .build();

    dispatcher.mustSchedule(myJob);
```

This time onStartJob executed
Now I am stopping job when call finished

```
 FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(ctx));
        dispatcher.cancel("my-unique-tag1");
```

But this time onStopJob not executed.
Can anyone please tell me where i'am doing wrong.

Comment: did you try using job id to start and stop it?

Comment: @quicklearner How can i use job id in FirebaseJobDispatcher????

Comment: are you starting only one service at a time or different also ?

Comment: @quicklearner at incoming and outgoing time i start only one service but there are some other services performing other task

Comment: give me a moment please

Comment: are you following any example for that?

Comment: @quicklearner No.

Comment: try my answer :)

Comment: did you get the answer yet? if yes can you please share

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: In my case onStopJob() method never get called. Even I am returning false from onStartJob and calling jobFinished from my background thread.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution for your problem

When you start the job just check if the `FirebaseRecordingService.Class` service class is running or not by using this method

```
 private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

your code looks like ths

```
if (isMyServiceRunning(context_here)) {
                                    System.out.println("service already started stopping now");
                                    stopService(new Intent(context_here, FirebaseRecordingService.class));
                                }
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("MobileNumber", number);
    bundle.putString("CallStatus", "OUT");
    FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(ctx));
    Job myJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
            .setService(FirebaseRecordingService.class) // the JobService that will be called
            .setTag("my-unique-tag1")        // uniquely identifies the job
            .setExtras(bundle)
            .build();
    dispatcher.mustSchedule(myJob);
```

**Then to when the work is executed to stop the service which is firebase job**

Do this

```
if (isMyServiceRunning(context_here)) {
    System.out.println("service already started stopping now");
        stopService(new Intent(context_here,FirebaseRecordingService.class));
                                }
```

> **And do not call this**

`FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(ctx));`

> it will create another object of FirebaseJobDispatcher class  Use the
>   declared object which is used to start the job service

```
dispatcher.cancel("my-unique-tag1");
```

Or you can call if there is only one service running at a time

```
dispatcher.cancelAll();
```

Comment: how can i get previous firebasejobdispatcher object because if app gets killed it will be null. should i use dispatcher.cancel() to stop service or stopService()?

Comment: for that case u should stop rather than calling dispatcher.cancel() , its better to stop service rather than cancelling dispatcher

Comment: I have tried to use stopService() to stop but it is not working. And isMyServiceRunning(context_here) method always return true even after stopService() method

Comment: can u post this class here FirebaseRecordingService.class ?

Comment: i have created a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51780753/cant-stop-firebase-jobdispatcher-service Can you please comment on it?

Comment: Now i m using foreground service for that task