# Cant stop Firebase JobDispatcher service

Tags: android, android-service, firebase-job-dispatcher

[Possible Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51646130/firebasejobdispatcher-onstopjob-not-triggering/51646685?noredirect=1#comment90518162_51646685)

I have created a JobDispatcher service to keep getting user location in background and post user location to server. For that i have created a Job as follow:

```
private void startLocationJobService() {
        // Check if location job service already running
        if(!isMyServiceRunning(LocationJobService.class)) {
            Context context = config.getActivity();
            FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(context));
            Job job = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
                    .setLifetime(Lifetime.FOREVER)
                    .setService(LocationJobService.class)
                    .setTag(JOB_SERVICE_TAG)
                    .setReplaceCurrent(true)
                    .build();

            //creating new job and adding it with dispatcher
            dispatcher.mustSchedule(job);
        }
    }

private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) config.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

In service's onStartJob i am configuring location api to get user location

```
public boolean onStartJob(final JobParameters job) {
        Log.i("TAG", "Service Run onStartJob called");
        configureFusedLocation(LocationJobService.this);
        return true;
    }
```

Service starts and keep running as expected. But it does not stop. I have used both ways (dispatcher.cancel and stopService) to stop service as follow:

```
public void stopService() {
        if(isMyServiceRunning(LocationJobService.class)) {
            config.getActivity().stopService(new Intent(config.getActivity(), LocationJobService.class));
            cancelLocationJobService();
        }
    }

private void cancelLocationJobService(){
        FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(config.getActivity()));
        // Cancel the job for this tag
        dispatcher.cancel(JOB_SERVICE_TAG);
        //Cancel all the jobs for this package
        dispatcher.cancelAll();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to cancel job in itself by unregistering location listener and calling `jobFinished()` inside LocationJobService.

As `dispatcher.cancelAll()` works only to cancel **scheduled jobs which are yet to be run**. 
You may use tools like `Eventbus` to inform service when to stop.

Refer https://medium.com/google-developers/scheduling-jobs-like-a-pro-with-jobscheduler-286ef8510129 for more info.

Comment: so i need to inform service to stop itself. Can i use LocalBroadcastManager to send broadcast from activity to service to notify service to stop?

Comment: In onStartJob i have made JobParameters global variable and then in onReceive of BroadcastReceiver i am calling jobFinished(jobParameters, false); But still service doest not does not stop, i keep getting location updates. Neither onStopJob() gets called. Any suggestion?

Comment: are you unregistering location listener while calling `jobFinished ` ?

Comment: yes now i am unregistering location listener, sure location updates get stopped but still it does not call onStopJob() which means service is still running.

Comment: **onStopJob() is called by the system if the job is cancelled before being finished.**

Comment: It means onStopJob() is not necessary to get called on service stop. Now here is what i am doing, first i am unregistering location listener, then calling stopSelf(); and then i am calling jobFinished(jobParameters, false); does that ensure that service is completely stopped?